# depth sensor recommendation_wonder if there is update

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

This is my first post here, I wonder if you guys know some good depth sensor for depth information? We want to generate something like a point cloud to show how far away a certain surface is to the robot arm end effect.

I know this post [1](http://answers.ros.org/question/222454/depth-sensing-camera-recommendation/), but it is 2 years ago. I wonder if there is update on this?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264679/depth-sensor-recommendation_wonder-if-there-is-update/) by [thompson104](https://answers.ros.org/users/30900/thompson104/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/Sensors#A3D_Sensors_.28range_finders_.26_RGB-D_cameras.29 is kept up to date.

You'll find it hard to find the Asus or kinetic these days as they have been discontinued. The Orbbec Astra is the most current tech.

I'd recommend a https://www.slamtec.com/en/Lidar as a 2D scanner - very good and easy to use

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2017-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thompson104](https://answers.ros.org/users/30900/thompson104/) on 2017-06-26**:
thank you.